# Unrecognized Windows Sockets error in JMeter

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap, jmeter

I just created a sample WCF webservice in ASP.net. The WebService have 2 methods. I am using first method which is accepting one integer argument. If I send a parameter like:

> "123"

to the method It will give a output like this:

> "You entered: 123"

Well I am testing this WebService using JMeter. It's not giving any error if I test with 1000 users. If I try with 10,000 users at some point some request are giving error.The error is:

```
Thread Name: webservice user 1-4836
Sample Start: 2017-06-30 13:02:34 IST
Load time: 323
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 000
Response message: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed

Response headers:

SampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/xml
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

ScreenShot of View Result Tree (Error):

[image: View Result Tree Screenshot]

Comment: Try adding to jmeter execution the following parameter -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Comment: I am using UI mode

Comment: You can add it also in UU mode

Comment: how can I do ..?

Comment: jmeter.bat -t jmx.jmx -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true